# How do we convert jQueryn $li.find('div.element:first') in VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does querySelectorAll() accept `('div.element:first')` this type of argument? I need to convert below jQuery method in VanillaJS

jQUery :

```
$li = $(this)
$li.find('div.element:first')
```

Vanilla :

```
var li = event.target;
li.querySelectorAll('div.element:first');
```

But the Vanilla script is not working as same as jQuery. Someone please suggest any better solution

Comment: What does `$li` represent?

Comment: `$li` represent -> `$li = $(this)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery's `:first` reduces the set of matched elements to the first in the set.

In other words, you get the first element matching `div.element`.

To do the same in plain javascript, all you have to do is call `querySelector` without the `All` part

```
var first = li.querySelector('div.element');
```

As `querySelector` will return the first element that matches the specified selector anyway

This of course only works if `li` is a single element, `querySelector` doesn't work on collections the way jQuery's `find()` does.

If `li` is not a single element, you have to iterate, but since you're only looking for the first element, you could just do

```
var first = li[0].querySelector('div.element');
```

Comment: `li.querySelectoAll('div.element')[0]`. This will work was well.

Comment: @Nicholas - I wasn't aware that there was a `nodeList.first` property ?

Comment: You've changed `first` to `[0]`, which is fine, at least that works, but it does the same as just calling `querySelector` instead.

Comment: Ups my bad. I updated. Basically queryselectorAll returns an array of objects and we can grab it like this.

Comment: In fact difference between `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` is the latter returns collection (NodeList) and the former returns only first occurrence (one Element). So it depends what OP needs.

Comment: @ArmanP. - The OP is using `:first`, and is trying to use it in plain JS as well, so clearly the OP wants the first element that matches the selector, which is what `querySelector` does

Comment: @adeneo my bad, haven't noticed `:first`, so yeah, `querySelector` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @adeneo since `$li` represent -> `$(this)` ,  `var first = li.querySelector('div.element');` worked fine. WDYT ?